# Is there a way to prevent your windows from moving when an external monitor is connected?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, external-monitor

So, I'm using Ubuntu 14.10 on my laptop and occasionally plug it into my TV for a second screen. My TV is to the left of my desk. When I enable it as an external monitor to the left of my laptop screen all of the windows that were in my laptop screen move over to the TV screen. I can move them back, but it's really annoying to have to do so every time, especially when there are several windows open.

[image: TV on Left]

The windows do not move, however, if I set my TV screen to the right of my laptop screen (virtually). But this is understandably confusing to use since it's the opposite of the physical setup. Also, I don't want to move my desk.

[image: TV on Right]

It seems like Ubuntu or the display server simply assumes that the leftmost monitor is the main one and where all the windows should be. Is there a way to disable this behavior?

I've been checking these forums but haven't really seen anyone post about this. The closest thread I found was this one, though it's not quite the same issue.

[Get Ubuntu to NOT move windows when turning off one of multiple monitors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429991/get-ubuntu-to-not-move-windows-when-turning-off-one-of-multiple-monitors)

Anyone have any ideas? Please let me know if you do. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I did not find a "secret" setting to change the behaviour of the, as it seems, designed behaviour. It looks indeed as if the left screen is assumed to be the "base" screen.

It is however very well possible to create a workaround, with essentially the same result. You can create a script that, on the occasion of connecting a second screen, lists all windows. Subsequently, all windows that are moved initially to the left screen, are shifted back to the screen on the right, within a second or two. The size of all windows will be preserved.
That is what the script below does.

#### Two versions

You can restore your arranged windows in two ways:

- Occasionally, with a shortcut key to run after the second screen is connected.
- Automatically, running the script in the background, waiting for your screen to be connected.

#### How to use

*preparations*

- Install `wmctrl`

  sudo apt-get install wmctrl
- Look up your two screens' names with the help of `xrandr`, the names of the screens will be just before the word "connected".
- Copy Either one of the scripts below, in the head section, replace in these two lines the screen names by the correct ones:

  ```
  screen_1 = "LVDS1"     # your main screen (laptop)
  screen_2 = "VGA1"      # secundary screen (on the left)
  ```

  save the script as `move_windows.py`
- Make sure in display settings your secondary screen is on the left. The top lines of the two screens need to be in line (like in the first image of your question).

*Run the script*
- If you use the one to run occasionally, run it after your second screen is connected.

```
    python3 /path/to/move_windows.py
```

You might want to add it to a keyboard shortcut if you think it does what it should do, Choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". 
Click the "+" and add the command:

- If you use the one to run in the background, also run it by the command:

  ```
  python3 /path/to/move_windows.py
  ```

  If it acts as you intended, add it to your start-up applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add

I tested the script with my laptop (on the right) and two different screens (on the left). The result was the same.

*laptop screen*

[image]

*connecting without script*

[image]

*connecting with the script running*

[image]

After the script did its job, windows will be "left alone" (of course), and you can arrange your windows your way.

#### The script(s)

*1. "Manual" version, to run after the screen is connected*

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time

#--
screen_2 = "LVDS1"       # replace with your internal screen (right)
screen_2 = "VGA1"        # replace with your external screen (left)
#--

def get(cmd):
    return subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c",  cmd]).decode("utf-8")

def get_shift(xr_output):
    lines = [l for l in xr_output.splitlines() if " connected" in l][0].split()
    return int([it for it in lines if "x" in it][0].split("x")[0])

def shift_windows(shift):
    w_data = [l.split() for l in get("wmctrl -lG").splitlines()]
    relevant = []
    for w in w_data:
        props = get("xprop -id "+w[0])
        if (int(w[2]) < shift, "_TYPE_NORMAL" in props, "TYPE_DIALOG" in props).count(True) == 2:
            command = "wmctrl -ir "+w[0]+" -e 0,"+(",").join([str(int(w[2])+shift), w[3], w[4], w[5]])
            subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", command])

shift_windows(get_shift(get("xrandr")))
```

*2. Automatic version, to run in the background*

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time

#--
screen_2 = "LVDS1"       # replace with your internal screen (right)
screen_2 = "VGA1"        # replace with your external screen (left)
#--

def get(cmd):
    return subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c",  cmd]).decode("utf-8")

def get_shift(xr_output):
    lines = [l for l in xr_output.splitlines() if " connected" in l][0].split()
    return int([it for it in lines if "x" in it][0].split("x")[0])

def shift_windows(shift):
    w_data = [l.split() for l in get("wmctrl -lG").splitlines()]
    relevant = []
    for w in w_data:
        props = get("xprop -id "+w[0])
        if (int(w[2]) < shift, "_TYPE_NORMAL" in props, "TYPE_DIALOG" in props).count(True) == 2:
            command = "wmctrl -ir "+w[0]+" -e 0,"+(",").join([str(int(w[2])+shift), w[3], w[4], w[5]])
            subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", command])

while True:
    try:
        screen_info1 = get("xrandr")
        time.sleep(5)
        screen_info2 = get("xrandr")
        check = screen_2+" connected"
        if (check in screen_info1, check in screen_info2) == (False, True):
            time.sleep(5)
            shift_windows(get_shift(screen_info2))
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Seriously sick skills, Jacob!

Comment: @K0j0 Did you manage?

Comment: @JacobVlijm Not sure if polling every 5 seconds is the best solution (is there no event-driven possibility?). Anyway, if you're interested in turning this script into a Unity indicator ([like these here](http://www.howtogeek.com/118908/10-awesome-indicator-applets-for-ubuntus-unity-desktop/)) then please get in touch.

Comment: @Peterino If an event-driven signal exists, it would be my first choice. At the same time: *If* a background script is well-written, its additional burden should (and can) be practically none, and I always test my scripts specifically on that. I run a changing number of background scripts myself. Even all together have no noticeable effect whatsoever. Remember numerous loops are running by definition on your system.  About the Unity indicator suggestion: I am *definitely* interested in learning how to create an indicator, either for this or another situation :).

Comment: @JacobVlijm Looks like the automatic placement of windows will happen automatically starting with one of the next releases of Ubuntu ("work in progress"), according to [a source at Canonical](https://lists.launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone/msg16985.html). It's probably not worth investing in the remaining few months on the current release. I'll double-check with the Mir developers on IRC #ubuntu-mir@freenode, though.

Comment: @Peterino the question was from December '14 :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm What do you intend to say? It's still not working out-of-the-box on Ubuntu. Canonical is working on this issue with [Ubuntu bug 1518317 in Mir](https://bugs.launchpad.net/mir/+bug/1518317) _"Client display configuration is not unapplied when the client doesn't explicitly release its surfaces before disconnecting"_ [High,Confirmed] -- `alan_g` on IRC adds: _"[T]hat sounds as though it cross-cuts Mir, Qtmir and Unity8. There's some work in Mir that will likely be landing in 0.18 and Gerry and I started on some Qtmir work that impacts it this week. Don't know about U8 though."_

Comment: Anyone interested in current advancements of a solution integrated in Unity can follow-up on IRC in either [#ubuntu-mir](http://irclogs.ubuntu.com/2015/11/27/%23ubuntu-mir.html) or [#ubuntu-desktop](http://irclogs.ubuntu.com/2015/11/27/%23ubuntu-desktop.html#t12:51).

Answer (score 1):

I have multiple monitors connected to a HDMI switch and whenever I switch from one device to another the previous device acts like the monitor has been turned off. So I wanted something like this for my laptop (I use both screens there)

@JacobVlijm wasn't quite the thing I wanted, but based **heavily** on that I made a bash script to move some (or all) windows from one screen to another.
Features:

- It doesn't care about "left and right", just "from and to".
- Can filter which apps you want to move
- Does it best to preserve windows size (works perfect when maximized, decent when not)
- Can be used in bash_aliases so you don't have to remember where the script is

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/Redithion/a68366ab0b4d24eb0e59aa7029a77e9c)

### Code

```bash
screen_from=${1:-'eDP-1'}
screen_to=${2:-'HDMI-1'}

echo "Moving windows from $screen_from to $screen_to"

apps_to_move=("Firefox" "Gnome-terminal" "Slack" "Sublime_text" "Terminator" "Thunderbird" "Mysql-workbench")

dimensions=`xrandr --listmonitors | grep $screen_to | cut -d ' ' -f4`
width=$(echo $dimensions | cut -f1 -d '/')
height=$(echo $dimensions | cut -f2 -d '/' |cut -f2 -d'x')
offset_x=$(echo $dimensions | cut -f2 -d '+')
offset_y=$(echo $dimensions | cut -f3 -d '+')

dimensions=`xrandr --listmonitors | grep $screen_from | cut -d ' ' -f4`
width_from=$(echo $dimensions | cut -f1 -d '/')
height_from=$(echo $dimensions | cut -f2 -d '/' |cut -f2 -d'x')
offset_x_from=$(echo $dimensions | cut -f2 -d '+')
offset_y_from=$(echo $dimensions | cut -f3 -d '+')

# Parameters: app_name (WM_CLASS or id)
move_window() {
    local app_name=$1

    # Looks for all windows of a given app (only need when WM_CLASS is provided)
    for app in `wmctrl -lGx | grep $app_name | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f1`; do
        echo "Processing $app_name - ID: $app"

        cur_offset_x=`wmctrl -lGx | grep $app | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f3`

        # Skip if window is already on dest screen
        if [[ $cur_offset_x -lt $offset_x_from ]]; then
            echo "$app is already on desired screen"
            continue
        fi

        echo "Moving $app"
        cur_width=`wmctrl -lGx | grep $app | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f5`
        cur_height=`wmctrl -lGx | grep $app | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f6`

        # echo "Cur width: $cur_width - Cur height: $cur_height"
        # echo "Width from: $width_from - Height from: $height_from"

        # Needed because otherwise wmctrl doesn't move the window
        wmctrl -ir $app -b remove,maximized_vert,maximized_horz

        # If app is maximized then it should be maximized in dest screen
        # 100 is the threshold to consider "maximized" because taskbars add offsets to windows
        if (( ($width_from - $cur_width < 100) && ($height_from - $cur_height < 100) )); then
            echo "App should be maximized"
            wmctrl -ir $app -e 0,$offset_x,$offset_y,-1,-1
            wmctrl -ir $app -b add,maximized_vert,maximized_horz
        else
            # Instead of keeping the original size I chose to preserve it's ratio in the source screen
            echo "App should preserve it's original size (ratio)"
            new_width=`bc <<< $width*$cur_width/$width_from`
            new_height=`bc <<< $height*$cur_height/$height_from`
            wmctrl -ir $app -e 0,$offset_x,$offset_y,$new_width,$new_height
        fi
    done
}

# If apps_to_move is not empty, use it
if (( ${#apps_to_move[@]} > 0 )); then
    echo "Using apps_to_move"
    for app in "${apps_to_move[@]}"; do
        move_window $app x
    done
# Else, move everything
else
    for app in `wmctrl -l | cut -d ' ' -f 1`; do
        move_window $app i
    done
fi
```